# Uploading file using ajax throws Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

Jquery version used is jquery 1.7.1
on clicking uplod button it shows error as Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

```js
$('#upload').on('click',function(){
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('fw_file',$("#fw_file")[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+'fieldwork/savefieldwork',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: form,
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="fieldworkform" id="fieldworkform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fw_file" id="fw_file">
<input type="button" value="Upload" name="fileupload" id="upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Wow, that's an old version of jQuery. Are you also using an old browser? What browser and version are you seeing this on?

Comment: Why are you suppressing the `Content-Type` request header?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you have to when uploading `FormData`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Really? Why?

Comment: @OP your code seems fine in isolation. Check the error in the console. It should tell you exactly which line of code is causing the issue. If it's buried somewhere in jquery.js, check the stack for a reference to your own code.

Comment: ** i can't change jquery to newer one it is old project that needs new updation. my browser is  chrome  and version is 68**

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% certain why jQuery requires it. A content type header *has* to be set, so I'm presuming there's some internal operation that occurs when you set it to `false`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Huh.

Comment: @PurushothGunasekaran - Your code works for me on Chrome 68 on \*nix (with jQuery v1.7.1).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks i will check